# Having trouble 301 redirecting a paramaterised URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, parameters

I've searched around for this, but can't get a solution to the specific situation.

I want to redirect an old URL to a new URL.

The old URL is this: http://www.example.org.uk/index.html?parents-welcome.html=&2=

The new URL is: http://www.example.org.uk

Any help on setting up the redirect would be hugely well received, I've been wrestling with this for ages..

Comment: Must you match the exact query parameters? Or is it any request to `index.html`?

Comment: Happy to redirect anything to index.html

Answer (score 0):

Place the following in your .htaccess file with the rest of your `RewriteRule`. If you are not already using mod_rewrite, [read up](http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/).

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [L,QSA,R=301]
```

You may be able to use `Redirect`, but I am unsure if it appends the query string.

#### UPDATE

If you don't want the query string, drop the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Jason - however this doesn't get rid of the parameters; it just strips out the "index.html".  Getting rid of the parameters is the part that I'm struggling to find guidance on.

Comment: @Jason and @Luke: if the server is still adding the querystring, try adding a `?` in the destination URL like so `RewriteRule ^index.html$ /? [L,R=301]`. I think this should eliminate the query string. Make sure that you refresh the cache every now and then during testing.